# Bootstrap 3 Form Validation Using built-in Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to implement form validation using Bootstrap3's CSS (For Example: On Submit, assuming all forms are filled in correctly, display an "alert alert-success". If failed, display "alert alert-danger" containing an explanation to the failure (Ex: Please enter a valid name). Right now, all I can get to work is requiring text in a field (using HTML5 required tag) without the ability to display any alerts.

Current Code:
http://pastebin.com/AjfUA26n

Website: http://infenterprises.com/contact/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

1. Do server side validation. Client side validation can be a nice help for your user, but it doesn't replace server side validation for security reasons. That being said
2. you will need to use Javascript to do client side validation and display the result. A nice helper when using bootstrap is http://bootstrapvalidator.com/.

Comment: Thank you wedi, I was able to implement that method without a problem though I've run into a small issue regarding the Error message. I'm able to display the message but i've been unable to get it to remove the div once the problem(s) has/have been fixed. Example: If the user doesn't enter anything and submits, the validation fails and displays an error indicating each problem that needs to be fixed. I would like to make it so when each of those problems are fixed, the Error Div becomes hidden again..

Comment: Great to hear I could help you. I suggest you close this question and open an new one with details about your problem.